# Intervals given by sum of integers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Consider the sequence $s_n=\displaystyle\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. It is easy to see that this sequence divides the integers in disjoint intervals $[s_n,s_{n+1})$.

Let $x,y$ integers contained in $[s_n,s_{n+1})$  and $[s_m,s_{m+1})$ respectively. There exist exactly one integer $k$ such that $x+y\in [s_k,s_{k+1})$.

> Is there any way to find such a $k$ in term of $x,y,n$ and $m$?

I have been thinking about it for a while without too much success.

I begin trying to find the $k$ for $s_m+s_n$ which should be easy enough. If $m>n$ then $k$ is the integer such that $s_m=s_k-s_n+r$ where $r$ is a "reminder" with $r<k+1$.

Any advice to solver this problem is very much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure I follow.  If you know $x,y$ you know $x+y$, and at that point it's easy to solve $\frac {k(k+1)}2=x+y$ (though of course the $k$ you get might not be an integer.).  Rounding it down gives you the value you want, no?

Comment: Take, say, $x+y=129$ (to pick a random value).  Then we solve $k^2+k-2\times 129=0$ to get$k=\frac {-1+\sqrt{1+8\times 129}}2=15.570...$ so the answer you want is $15$ in this case.

Comment: Yeah... You are completely right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

Let $$f(x)=\frac{x(x+1)}{2}, x\ge 0$$

$ f $ is bijective since it is continuous and strictly increasing at $ [0,+\infty)$ with
$$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8x}}{2}$$

$$x\in[s_n,s_{n+1})\implies$$
$$f(n)\le x<f(n+1)\implies$$

$$n\le f^{-1}(x)<n+1\implies$$

$$n=\lfloor f^{-1}(x)\rfloor$$
thus
$$k=\lfloor f^{-1}(x+y )\rfloor$$
$$=\lfloor \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8(x+y)}}{2}\rfloor$$

There is a link between your question and what is called "triangular numbering" of $ \Bbb N^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us solve $$\frac{k(k+1)}2\le z<\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}2$$

or

$$\left(k+\frac12\right)^2\le 2z+\frac14<\left(k+\frac32\right)^2$$

and

$$k\le\sqrt{2z+\frac14}-\frac12<k+1,$$

which is equivalent to

$$k=\left\lfloor\sqrt{2z+\frac14}-\frac12\right\rfloor.$$